Optimize multiple SQL queries with similar joins and conditions in a stored procedure
I'm currently working with a large dataset in SQL Server, and I have three different SELECT queries that I need to execute, each with slightly different conditions:
-- Query 1
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID > 80;

-- Query 2
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID = 1;

-- Query 3
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE Country = 'Mexico';

Each query uses the same set of JOIN clauses and additional conditions like this:
FROM Customers C
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN OtherTables OT ON C.SomeID = OT.SomeID
WHERE C.Active = 1 -- Common condition
  AND O.OrderStatus = 'Completed'

My Current Approach
I'm using a stored procedure where I execute all three queries one after another, and each result is stored in a different variable using SET:
SET @result1 = (/* Query 1 with common joins and conditions */);
SET @result2 = (/* Query 2 with common joins and conditions */);
SET @result3 = (/* Query 3 with common joins and conditions */);

However, executing these queries takes a lot of time due to the large amount of data, and sometimes it even kills the session, resulting in no output.
What I need help with

Optimization: how can I optimize this stored procedure to reduce execution time and prevent the session from getting killed?

Efficient use of joins: is there a way to avoid repeating the common JOIN and WHERE conditions for each query while still storing the results in separate variables?

Best practices: are there any best practices for handling multiple queries with similar joins and conditions in SQL Server?


I attempted to use CTEs to reduce repetition, but CTEs only allow one SELECT statement to follow, which doesn't work for my requirement of storing multiple results into different variables.
Any suggestions on how to optimize these queries or the stored procedure itself would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not sure what you mean about storing resultsets in variables - since you can't do that in SQL Server.

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

OK your question as asked is too broad, as in you are asking too many questions in one question. However here is an approach to minimise the processing when using a similar result set with different WHERE clauses as you ask in your second question:

Build a temp table with all the IDs of the primary table (e.g. Customer) and a bit column to indicate whether it matches a specific criteria. Use UNION ALL because it performs better, but then GROUP BY to avoid having duplicate rows.
Join this temp table onto all the other common tables you need to join and SELECT all the data you need for all your subsequent queries. Put this result into another temp table.
Then you can perform your individual queries against your final results temp table, using the criteria bit columns to ensure you select the correct rows.
Performance (your question 1) beyond this would require inspecting your execution plan and determining whether additional indexes etc are required.
Best practices, thats not on topic for StackOverflow... because its a matter of opinion. My personal approach is, write a query so that it logically makes sense. If it doesn't perform well, then carry out a performance investigation and improve it. Keep in mind DRY frequently doesn't apply when it comes to SQL.

An outline example follows
-- Query 1
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id, 1 AS Criteria1, 0 AS  Criteria2, 0 AS  Criteria3  
    FROM Customers
    WHERE CustomerID > 80;

    UNION ALL

    -- Query 2
    SELECT id, 0, 1, 0
    FROM Customers
    WHERE CustomerID = 1;

    UNION ALL

    -- Query 3
    SELECT id, 0, 0, 1
    FROM Customers
    WHERE Country = 'Mexico'
)
SELECT Id, MAX(Criteria1) Criteria1, MAX(Criteria2) Criteria2, MAX(Criteria3) Criteria3
INTO #temp_table1
FROM cte
GROUP BY Id;

SELECT Id, Criteria1, Criteria2, Criteria3 -- and other required columns
INTO #temp_table2
FROM #temp_table1
-- JOIN table1
-- JOIN table2
-- etc

SELECT *
FROM #temp_table2
WHERE Criteria1 = 1;

SELECT *
FROM #temp_table2
WHERE Criteria2 = 2;

SELECT *
FROM #temp_table2
WHERE Criteria3 = 3;


WHERE Criteria1 = 2; should be WHERE Criteria2 = 1;?

My answer would be logically same as to @Dale's.
you can create a common table which has same logic and then create 3 temporary tables.
Regarding performance, you can create index on CommonData table on customerId and country as they are in filtering condition.
example:
CREATE TABLE #CommonData (
-- Column definitions
);

INSERT INTO #CommonData
SELECT 
    C.*, 
    O.*, 
    OT.*
FROM Customers C
LEFT JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN OtherTables OT ON C.SomeID = OT.SomeID
WHERE C.Active = 1 AND O.OrderStatus = 'Completed';

SELECT * FROM #CommonData WHERE CustomerID > 80;
SELECT * FROM #CommonData WHERE CustomerID = 1;
SELECT * FROM #CommonData WHERE Country = 'Mexico';

